# Add an option to extend bounties?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I have the following question:

[When using ActionMode, the status bar turns black on Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180091/when-using-actionmode-the-status-bar-turns-black-on-lollipop)

The bounty *did* attract a large amount of attention, which was my original purpose for putting the bounty on the question in the first place. However, my problem still hasn't been solved. Further, it looks as though the question has a solution, and that the folks answering the question are close to helping me find a solution.

I have no qualms about starting a new bounty, but in reality, all I really need is a little more time. When a bounty expires, perhaps what it should do is give you the option to "extend" the bounty for another 7 days for another `+<bounty value>` rep.

For example, since my bounty is 50 right now, it would give me the option to extend the bounty for another 7 days for an additional 50 reputation. Next time, it would give me the option to extend the bounty for an additional 7 days for an additional 100 reputation. (Up to a maximum of, say, 3 extensions).

This might be useful in the case where a solution is close, but it just isn't in the answers yet. Of course, it might also give the incentive to sandbag one's answers, but that assumes the author is going to extend the bounty, which he/she has no requirement to do.

Perhaps just allowing extensions within the grace period would be a useful addition?

Comment: When adding additional bounties to a question the minimum bounty size goes up with each additional bounty; that would need to be maintained in this model, so a 50 point bounty would need to require 100 *additional* rep to extend it, not 50.  Other than that, this seems fine, assuming the devs actually feel like it's worth their time to implement this over just having the few people in this situation place a second bounty.

Comment: @Servy: Well, the idea was that if you chose to _extend_ the bounty, within the grace period, you'd sort of get a _discount_, indicating that you're still actively pursuing an answer within the allotted time frame (rather than just coming back at some later date).

Comment: I see no reason to provide such a discount.  They want an additional 7 days of attention, they need to pay for it.  That they determined that they want to buy another 7 days of attention sooner, rather than later, isn't particularly advantageous to the system, so I see no reason to reward it.

Comment: yes, a discount would provide a way to get extra attention for less payment

Comment: @Servy: Well, in my opinion, it would notify the system that the OP is still actively engaged with the question. I've found that there are situations where I perhaps forgot about a particular question for a while before coming back and accepting an answer. "Extending" the bounty within the time frame would indicate to the system that the OP still needs an answer, and has read through the active answers at the current time.

Comment: Also, it would provide the means to not allow awarding of the bounty immediately. (i.e. noone gets the pot if the question's bounty is extended).

Comment: @jwir3 I don't see a significant problem of bountied questions lacking sufficient attention, but even if they did, *it's just not all that important*.  If someone wants to pay for a bunch of attention and then ignore the attention given, that's up to them.  If the question is a good question, and the added attention attracts good responses, then great.  If no attention is needed, then no attention is needed.  Whether the person who posted the bounty solved their problem or not isn't a major concern.  That they didn't doesn't mean we need to give them a cheaper bounty.

Comment: @jwir3 That the first bounty wouldn't be awarded is the only real change I see here, and frankly that just doesn't seem worth the work.  All of the important functionality already exists, and it would take considerable dev work, as well as considerably complicating the user experience of using the feature, for something that just doesn't seem to add *that* much value.

Comment: @Servy: Well, I'm just proposing a suggestion, with the rationale as to why I think that's the way to go. I guess I'm sort of suggesting that the bounty system be revamped a little bit. I would argue that the bounty system _should_ exist to help original posters to get satisfactory answers to their questions, not just to attract attention. Plus, I don't know what the SE codebase looks like, so it's possible that it's not as complex as it might appear at first glance.

Comment: @Servy: I think we just have a difference of opinion. ;)

Comment: @jwir3 But the purpose *is* to provide a way for people to get additional attention to their post, in exchange for rep.  You're buying attention, not answers.  That is the goal of the system.  This has been made very explicit by SE.

Comment: @Servy: Oh, I guess I didn't realize that had been made clear, then. It seems odd, on the surface, right? I mean, a "Bounty" is something that is awarded for a _result_, right? (i.e. you don't award a bounty to a bounty hunter that comes in with the wrong criminal just because it seems like it _could_ be that person, given that his face was messed up in the preceding struggle with the bounty hunter, right?) :)

Comment: @jwir3 It's the reason why you aren't refunded the bounty if it's not awarded to anyone.  You paid to advertise the question.  That someone else could earn that reputation for a good answer is simply the means by which that additional attention is actually accomplished.

Comment: Ah. I thought it was to prevent abuse (e.g I simply let the question's bounty expire, even though a quality answer was present).

Comment: @jwir3 No, the auto-awarding of bounties is there to deal with that particular problem.

Answer (score 5):

On the surface this seems like a fairly reasonable idea, my only concern is the potential for abuse.

Chameleon questions are already a bit of a problem. I'm a little concerned that allowing users to extend a bounty may contribute to users adding or changing requirements after a good solution has already been reached.

As in, the original question asks for X with a bounty of 50 rep.

After X has been provided:
The question is changed to ask for X and Y, and  the bounty is raised to 100 rep

After X and Y have been provided:
The question is changed to ask for X, Y and Z and the bounty is raised to 150 rep

This may be just a corner case, but I can see this generating some disputes.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the possibility for abuse. Perhaps there could be a system to flag the bounty (non-) award for having this problem, and using a review system like we do currently?

Comment: @jwir3 It's way too much of a corner case to need a community review process.  There would be too few cases, and the decision would be too complex.  Problems like this (which, for the record, can happen just as easily with the existing system of adding a new bounty each time) can be solved by flagging for a mod.  They have the tools to resolve a problem like this, and it's exceptional enough that making mods responsible for resolving such problems isn't an issue.

Comment: @jwir3 The obvious thing, would be to roll-back edits that add requirements, but when bounties are involved things can get a little more intense...